# WordPress on Azure Site Unavailable

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

I decided to give Azure a try for my WordPress site hosting. I was able to successfully get a wordpress site running on the free tier and began to monitor the site in prep to move more sites over to azure.  Well, while on vacation I guess my FREE plan ran out and my site stopped working. I have upgraded my plan and tried to restart the app, but now I get a 503 and the site just says "The service is unavailable."

None of the logs are working and I can't figure out what is wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my case, I did not realize that this site was running on a separate app service plan than the other site I previously upscaled.  By changing the tier of this site to B1 instead of F1 I was able to get it working again. Still leanring azure...

Answer (score 1):

`503 error` is due to the server is currently unable to handle the request, and it is due to a temporary overload or maintenance of the server.

- In Azure Portal, in your app, you will be seeing the options to stop or restart your app, Restart the   app.

[image]

- Check the app logs and see if there are any errors or issues that causing the error 503.
- Check the [application gateway logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) if  configured for your app.
- Also verify the backend health and check for any issues with the backend servers.
- Scale your app to improve performance and throughput.

[image]

Azure Monitor

[image]

For more information refer to the
[HTTP response codes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/http-response-codes)